# How to replace specific digits in column using python pandas.

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, str-replace

How can I replace the specific digits in columns of pandas data frame without affecting other characters? I have a large csv file which is something similar like this:

```
data = pd.read_csv("meter.csv")
data.head()
Out[10]:
     value  temp1  temp2
0   34 02:0   16.0     17 
1   36 06:0    8.0     27
2   28 10:0   18.0     21
3   34 02:0   16.0     17 
4   36 06:0    8.0     27
5   28 10:0   18.0     21
6   34 02:0   16.0     17 
7   36 06:0    8.0     27
8   28 10:0   18.0     21
```

I want to replace `value` column values if `value.str[3:5] == 10` with `00`

Output that I need:

```
     value  temp1  temp2
0   34 02:0   16.0     17 
1   36 06:0    8.0     27
2   28 00:0   18.0     21
3   34 02:0   16.0     17 
4   36 06:0    8.0     27
5   28 00:0   18.0     21
6   34 02:0   16.0     17 
7   36 06:0    8.0     27
8   28 00:0   18.0     21
```

I tried with using `pd.str.replace` reference:[pandas.Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html). but could not able to achieve it.

My code: `data['value'] = data['value'].str[3:5].replace('10','00')` and this gives output:

```
   value  temp1  temp2
0   02   16.0     17 
1   06    8.0     27
2   00   18.0     21
3   02   16.0     17 
4   06    8.0     27
5   00   18.0     21
```

It is replacing entire values with new value. Could anyone help me to solve this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data['value'].str[3:5].replace('10','00')` returns a `pd.Series` consisting of each string sliced by `[3:5]` with the `replace` method applied in each row. What you're looking for is returning the whole string with `replace` applied in each row that matches your condition, which can be achieved like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({ # small part of your DF
    'value': ['34 02:0', '36 06:0', '28 10:0'], # Third row should be changed
    'temp1': [16.0, 8.0, 18.0],
    'temp2': [17, 27, 21] 
})

mask = data['value'].str[3:5] == '10'
data.loc[mask, 'value'] = data.loc[mask, 'value'].str.replace('10', '00')

>>> print(data)
     value  temp1  temp2
0  34 02:0   16.0     17
1  36 06:0    8.0     27
2  28 00:0   18.0     21 # Third row changes, yay!
```

This code could be introducing a bug if there's a value that matches '10' more than once, for example `10 10:0`. You can solve this by calling `.replace('10:', '00:')` instead.

You can also just use regex to match something like `r'\s10\:'` and call `.replace(re.compile(r'\s10\:'), ' 00:')`.

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'\s10\:')
data['value'] = data['value'].str.replace(r, ' 00:', regex=True) # no need to define a condition at all

>>> print(data)
     value  temp1  temp2
0  34 02:0   16.0     17
1  36 06:0    8.0     27
2  28 00:0   18.0     21
```

This last solution is not as explicit as the first one with your condition.

Comment: Awesome and clarifying explanation! Thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome and clarifying explanation! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can using np.where

```
df.value=np.where(df.value.str[3:5]=='10',df.value.str[:3]+'10'+df.value.str[5:],df.value)
df
Out[21]: 
     value  temp1  temp2
0  34 02:0   16.0     17
1  36 06:0    8.0     27
2  28 10:0   18.0     21
3  34 02:0   16.0     17
4  36 06:0    8.0     27
5  28 10:0   18.0     21
6  34 02:0   16.0     17
7  36 06:0    8.0     27
8  28 10:0   18.0      2
```

Or inspired by Tomas

```
df.value.str.replace(r'\s10\:',' 00:')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for alternative solution.!

Answer (score 1):

Using [`str.slice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.slice.html)

```
mask=df.value.str.slice(3,5) =='10'

df.loc[mask, 'value'] = df.loc[mask].value.str.slice(0,3) + '00' +  df.loc[mask].value.str.slice(5,)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple conditions and choice, I prefer

```
condition = [df.value.str[3:5]=='10']
choice= [df.value.str[:3]+'10'+df.value.str[5:]]
df.value= np.select(condition,choice,default=df.value)

#inspired by Beny
```

Output

```
  value  temp1  temp2
0  34 02:0   16.0     17
1  36 06:0    8.0     27
2  28 10:0   18.0     21
3  34 02:0   16.0     17
4  36 06:0    8.0     27
5  28 10:0   18.0     21
6  34 02:0   16.0     17
7  36 06:0    8.0     27
8  28 10:0   18.0      2
```